# Is it possible to receive a RTSP stream on the Raspberry Pi, and also resend it with a lower resolution and FPS?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, rtsp

Is it possible to receive and play a RTSP stream on the Raspberry Pi using gstreamer1.0 (with omx plugin in order to use hardware acceleration) and resend another RTSP stream with lower resolution and lower fps rate?

Can I process the lowered RTSP stream using opencv?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You will have to decode the stream, manipulate, re-encode, and then send it along its way.

Comment: @Pabzt, I tweaked your post to make it a little easier to read, and changed the title to (hopefully) make it more noticeable. Feel free to edit it again if I've changed it too much.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent Thank you for your comment. I just wanted to make sure if it is possible before I start compiling gstreamer on my raspberry pi. Can I use the command line or do I have to code this using gstreamer libraries/api in order to achieve the above described behavior? Do you have any hints on how to get started?

Comment: @BiscuitBaker okay, sorry. I'll try to be more specific and accurate next time. Thanks for your editing!

Comment: @Pabzt, you will have to write a program as you will have to make an RTSP server. This cannot be done with `gst-launch-1.0` from a terminal or through a script.